# Rounding the number to the specified precision

Tags: c++

The task is: I have number a=2.7182818284590452353602875.

It is 25 digits after comma. I need to write a program which will round this number to the specified precision.

The precision is constrained to be 0 < n < 100.

For example:

> Input: 0
>
> ```
> Output: 3
> ```
>
> Input: 25
>
> ```
> Output: 2.7182818284590452353602875
> ```
>
> Input: 4
>
> ```
> Output: 2.7183
> ```

and so on.

This is my code. It works fine, BUT I am going out of the `unsigned long long` range if n>17...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a=2.7182818284590452353602875;
    double b=a;

    unsigned long long c=a;
    int n;
    int kiek=0;
    cin>>n;

    while (1!=0){
b=b*10;
c=b;
if (kiek==n) break;
kiek++;
cout<<c<<endl;
    }
    cout<<c<<endl;
if((c%10)>4) {c=c/10+1;}
else {c=c/10;}


double atgal=1;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    atgal*=10;
}

cout<<endl<<atgal<<endl;
b=c;
b=b/atgal;
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(n)<<b;
}
```

Any suggestions about how to improve it or make it work?

Comment: If you want precision over a large amount of digit, you will be stopped by the precision of the type himself.
You can use a library like GMP.

Comment: [tag:c++] is not [tag:c]..

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is  this: The maximum accuracy of a double is about 17 digits. Even if you write `double a=2.7182818284590452353602875;` the last digits are ignored.

If you really need up to 100 digits og accuracy, you have to use a special library, one of these (GMP) has been mentioned in the comments.

If you do not need higher accuracy and only the output format is important for you, use this:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(n) << a;
```

Comment: Mhmm... thanks! But I can only use default libraries. I need to sent this to another compilator which I can't edit or include specific libraries...

Comment: setpreciosion just cuts out the numbers.. I need to mathematically round it :( E.g. 2.718 ~ 2.72

Comment: Add `fixed` to round: `std::cout << fixed << std::setprecision(n) << a;`

Comment: Ummm. The number is 2.7182818284590452353602875. I need to get 2.71828182845904523. Using MY code and n=17 I get              2.71828182845904465. Using std::cout << fixed << std::setprecision(n) << a I get 2.7182818284590409. wtf T___________________T

Comment: I have been exaggerating a bit when writing about 17 significant digits. Actually it is less. Plus, you also have to count the digit(s) before the decimal point. Number representation is a comples topic if you really get into the details. The method I suggested should work well as long as you keep well below the limit of floating point accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `printf` precision setting:

```
printf("%.*f", precision, value);
```

The output should be rounded (not just truncated) value according to the C++ and C standards (C:7.21.6.1.8: *"The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits."*).

Same result can be achieved using `iostreams`:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << value;
```

---

If you want to implement it yourself, you can do so without ever converting the value to an integer, e.g. using functions such as `ceil()`, `floor()`, or `modf()`.

Note that you can print an integer value stored in a `float` or `double` by printing it with the precision set to 0.

You can start of with the following code (no rounding, just truncating) and modify it to your needs.

```
double integerPart    = 0;
double fractionalPart = 0;
// print the integer part
fractionalPart = modf(value, &integerPart);
printf("%.0f", integerPart);
// print the decimal point
printf(".");
// print the fractional part digit by digit
for (int i = 0; i < precision; ++i) {
    fractionalPart *= 10;
    fractionalPart = modf(fractionalPart, &integerPart);
    printf("%.0f", integerPart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found new solution by myself ^^"

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sk[25]={7,1,8,2,8,1,8,2,8,4,5,9,0,4,5,2,3,5,3,6,0,2,8,7,5};
    int n=0;
    cin>>n;
    if(n==0) cout<<3;
    else if (n==25) {
            cout<<2<<".";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout<<sk[i];
        }
    }
    else{
    if (sk[n]>4){
            if(sk[n-1]==9){
                    sk[n-1]=0;
                    sk[n-2]++;
            }
    else sk[n-1]++;

    }
    cout<<2<<".";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<sk[i];
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks everyone for your replies!!! ^^